# Recursion in Select Statement for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursion, sql-server-2014

I have three SQL Server tables: `Projects`, `ProjectTree`, `ProjectTreeRec`.

`Projects` are analogous to directories and I am trying to find all sub-directories below a directory called `Standard Parts`. Clearly recursion is required here.

The `Projects` table has the following columns:

```
ProjectID, Name, Deleted
```

The `ProjectTree` table has the following columns:

```
ProjectID, ChildProject
```

I don't believe I need the `ProjectTreeRec` table as part of this effort, but it contains the columns `ChildProjectID`, `ParentProjectID`, `Level`.

I would like to develop a recursive select statement to find all subdirectories below the `Standard Parts` directory that have not been deleted (not 1, but 0).

I am new to CTE and recursion. I get some results, but not what I am after.

Here is the non-recursive call that finds me the first level down, but does not go deeper. It works fine.

```
SELECT 
    '(Directory Not Available)'

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT
    C.[Name] 
FROM 
    [EPDM].[dbo].[Projects] A
JOIN 
    [EPDM].[dbo].[ProjectTree] B ON B.ProjectID = A.ProjectID 
JOIN 
    [EPDM].[dbo].[Projects] C ON B.childproject = C.projectid 
WHERE
    A.name = 'Standard Part Library' 
    AND A.[Deleted] = 0;
```

Any help is welcomed.

Comment: Which version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: You can check it for recursive CTE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37973842/get-all-duplicate-data-by-parent-or-child-id-sql-server/37975448#37975448

Comment: I am using SQL Server Standard 2014.

Comment: SELECT
               SUBSTRING([Path], 0, (LEN([Path]) )) as [Path]
    FROM
    (
               SELECT
               -- replace the standard parts string with blank then replace the '\' from that with blank
                              REPLACE([Path], '\03-Standard Parts\', '') as [Path]
 
    FROM
               Projects
    Where
               [Path] Like '%Standard Parts%'
    and
               Deleted = 0
 
 
    ) as x

Comment: Side note: I'd recommend to get in the habit of using *more expressive, more meaningful* table alias than just `a` and `b` ..... `p` for `Projects`, `pt` for `ProjectTree` and `p2` for `Projects` (the second time it appears) would be **much more intuitive** to someone looking at your code

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like the following in order to evaluate the tree structure and then join the cte to your tables in order to get the names:

```
DECLARE @SearchProjectID int = 1;

WITH cteTree AS(
SELECT ProjectID, ChildProject
  FROM ProjectTree
  WHERE ProjectID = @SearchProjectID
UNION ALL
SELECT pt.ProjectID, pt.ChildProject
  FROM ProjectTree AS pt
  JOIN cteTree AS ct ON ct.ChildProject = pt.ProjectID
)
SELECT *
  FROM cteTree
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this...

```html
  CREATE TABLE #Project
(
ProjectID INT 
,Name varchar(50)
,Deleted bit
)

CREATE TABLE #ProjectTree
(
ProjectID INT, 
ChildProject INT
)

INSERT INTO #Project
(ProjectID,Name,Deleted)
SELECT 1,'Standard Part Library',0
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'P2',1
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'P3',0
UNION ALL SELECT 4,'P4',0

INSERT INTO #ProjectTree
(ProjectID,ChildProject)
SELECT 1,3
UNION SELECT 2,4

SELECT * FROM #Project
SELECT * FROM #ProjectTree

;WITH CTE_Project 
AS
(
SELECT 
 A.ProjectId
 ,B.ChildProject
 ,A.Name AS ProjectName
FROM #Project A
 INNER JOIN #ProjectTree B
  ON A.ProjectId = B.ProjectId
WHERE
 A.Name = 'Standard Part Library' 
 AND A.[Deleted] = 0

UNION ALL

SELECT 
 PT.ProjectID
 ,PT.ChildProject
 ,CP.ProjectName AS ProjectName
FROM 
 #ProjectTree AS PT
 INNER JOIN CTE_Project CP 
  ON PT.ChildProject = CP.ProjectID
)
SELECT 
ProjectName
,ProjectId
,ChildProject
FROM 
CTE_Project;
```

Comment: This does run but does not return the directories below Standard Parts - P2, P3, P4. Close but not quite there.